# Constructer error

Tags: apex

I created a function that I want to use in LWC, but when i first tested it the result was a ObjectObject. So i tried to test the function through Develper Console. So here is my function

```
public class Plan {
   @AuraEnabled
    public static string Plan(String jobName, String d, String scheduleName) {
       String jobId;
       Type scheduleClass = Type.forName(scheduleName);
       if (scheduleClass != null) {
           Schedulable m = (Schedulable) scheduleClass.newInstance();
            jobId = system.schedule(jobName, d, m);
       }
       return jobId;
   }
}
```

I tried using these for execution in the terminal

```
Plan A=new Plan('Test','0 0 13 * *  ?','PlanTest');
```

But I got an error Constructer not defined

Comment: You should not be able to save the class, it wd give compile time error

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Well i'm able to save it.

Comment: try, 
`String jobId - Plan.plan('Test','0 0 13 * *  ?','PlanTest');`

Comment: In my knowledge, Constructor is never static and never has a return type, the fact that you can make static constuctor with return type, amazes me, it looks like its not a constuctor, but just a normal static method?

Comment: Aha got the reason, :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480867/why-java-allows-method-that-has-class-name-and-type-void

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It worked the method you gave me. True what you are saying about constructors, but it was the error it showed me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you have not defined a `parameterized constructor` for class `Plan`.

What you have created in your class is a `static method` and not `Constructor`.

Excerpt from [Using Constructors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_constructors.htm) document.

> The syntax for a constructor is similar to a method, but it differs
>   from a method definition in that it never has an explicit return type
>   and it is not inherited by the object created from it.

**In your case, you have defined a `static method` with the same name as `class name` which is allowed but not recommended.**

So this is how constructors should be defined

```
public class Plan {
    // The no argument constructor 
    public Plan() {
        // more code here
    }

    // The parameterized constructor 
    public Plan(String jobName, String d, String scheduleName) {
        // more code here
    }
}
```

So when you want to execute your code, you should use

```
Plan.Plan('Test','0 0 13 * *  ?','PlanTest'); //calling static method
```

instead of

```
Plan A=new Plan('Test','0 0 13 * *  ?','PlanTest'); 
//this code will check for parameterized constructor which is not present, hence error would be thrown
```